# Android - how to get the default bluetooth communication device

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

With migration from `startBluetoothSco()` to `setCommunicationDevice()` I came to situation in which the user has 2 bluetooth communication devices connected.

With `startBluetoothSco()` the device was picked by the system.

Now, I have to decide which one to pick and I cannot really find the way to decide which one is the default one.

Is there some option to query this? Is there an option to get info about which device was connected more recently?